# Array Protocol Extension

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I am having a problem making an Array comply with a protocol.

I have defined a protocol which I use to tag types as able to store in my database:

```
protocol Storable {
}
```

now I want to make an String tagged as Storable

```
extension String: Storable {
}
```

An now I want an Array of Storable also tagged as Storable

```
extension Array: Storable where Element: Storable {
}
```

But, when I use this in this test example, an Array of type String is not seen as Storable

```
func x() -> Storable {
    var array: [Storable] = []
    return array // Error: Type 'any Storable' cannot conform to 'Storable'
}
```

I get an error: "Type 'any Storable' cannot conform to 'Storable'". But, I though I had defined an Array of values tagged with Storable to be Storable.

If I try the following:

```
extension Array: Storable where Element == Storable {
}
```

The test function now works OK:

```
func x() -> Storable {
    var array: [Storable] = []
    return array // No Error
}
```

But, not a concrete example using as String Array:

```
func y() -> Storable {
    var array: [String] = []
    return array // Error: 'y()' requires the types 'String' and 'any Storable' be equivalent
}
```

I get the error:
'y()' requires the types 'String' and 'any Storable' be equivalent

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not `func y() -> [String]`, what does using `Storable` add to the declaration? If the function can return any Storable then I would make it generic, `func y<T: Storable>() -> T`.

Comment: You are correct, that would work. The example is just that. It's part of a bigger code set which needs to return a storable. I created a test example for simplicity. Thanks.